# What is the 30th permutation of 1,3,5,7,9?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have the answer it is 31975, but my book doesn't show the method of how to get this answer. Can someone show me how to solve this because the book doesn't say anything regarding this problem... By the way. This is beginner combinatorics.

Comment: Hint: how many permutations start with $1$? With $3$? How many permutations start with $3,1$ or something less?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to explain how the book wants the permutations ordered and to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Usually, permutations are ordered using the lexicographical order. Is that the order your book uses for permutations?

Comment: Just because the general method is interesting: Given any positive integer $N$, there is a unique $k$ and a unique sequence of integers $a_k, a_{k-1}, \ldots, a_2, a_1, a_0$ such that $0\leq a_i \leq i$ and $N = \sum_{i=0}^k a_k \cdot k!$.  This method $0$-indexes the permutations, so the $30$th permutation has index $$30 - 1 = 1\cdot 4! + 0 \cdot 3! + 2\cdot 2! + 1 \cdot 1! + 0\cdot 0!$$ The coefficients, in order, are $1, 0, 2, 1, 0$ which tells you the order to choose the numbers.  "0" means the smallest remaining number, "1" means the next smallest remaining number, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First, as mihaild commented, think about how many permutations there are with a certain number starting. In other words, how many permutations start with 1?

There are 4! = 24 that start with 1 (since there are 4 digits remaining after the 1). Now, you need to come up with 6 more permutations to reach 30, and these will start with 3.

Now, think of how many permutations start not with just 3, but 31. There are 3! = 6, which is exactly what we needed!

So, starting with 31579, count 6 permutations in increasing order: 31579, 31597, 31759, 31795, 31957, and 31975, the last of which is our answer.